Framework Event Listeners API Errors: fetcher call produced error: ReferenceError: Property 'Node' doesn't exis
I am trying to log in but it shows this
enter image description hereenter image description here
when I tried to log in it shows Network request failed. I'm using expo react native and tried this to debug and it shows this. Anyone have any idea here?I'm new to react native
